# git submodule update checks out multiple times, how can I avoid or fix this issue?

Tags: git, git-submodules

$ git.exe submodule update --init --recursive --remote ABC_SDK

```
Cloning into 'D:/somedir/ABC_SDK'...
Submodule path 'ABC_SDK': checked out '27b8794752812baa55a9845f48c60438173f8cd9'
Submodule 'ABC_SDK' (RepoLink) registered for path 'ABC_SDK/ABC_SDK'
Cloning into 'D:/somedir/ABC_SDK/ABC_SDK'...
Submodule path 'ABC_SDK/ABC_SDK': checked out '27b8794752812baa55a9845f48c60438173f8cd9'
Submodule 'ABC_SDK' (RepoLink) registered for path 'ABC_SDK/ABC_SDK/ABC_SDK'
Cloning into 'D:/somedir/ABC_SDK/ABC_SDK/ABC_SDK'...
```

Comment: It seems like you have built a submodule that refers to itself as a submodule. Remember that a submodule is simply a reference that says "check out a commit from this other repository". If the "other" repository contains a reference to itself, every time you check out that submodule, it calls for another copy of itself.

Comment: The short version of how to avoid that is "don't do that".

Comment: Got rid of this issue. I am not sure exactly how the above situation is resolved .
In my case , Submodule is pointing to a commit that is equal to the parent repo commit ( observed it as a result after Jenkins pipeline execution , when a parent repo1 having Jenkins_groovy_file is trying to check out a repo2 which has submodule repo3) 
CommitId of repo1 is been overwitten to the submodule commitId
The overwitten is caused due to in my home .gitconfig file in Jenkins slave has the remote origin url entry pointing to repo1, once I remove this reference
The submodules are properly checkedout